# Magnitude of non-ergodicity effect on the individual's risk of bankruptcy

Tags: time-series, ergodic

[Dr. Ole Peters presents the concept of (non-)ergodicity with the following gambling example](https://youtu.be/f1vXAHGIpfc):

You're given $\$100$ to play a game where you toss a coin once a minute. If it comes up heads, you win $50\%$ of your wager, while you lose $40\%$ if tails. Averaging over $1$ million sequences (or players) results in the plot on the left below, which shows this is a favorable game:

[image]

This is the ensemble perspective, or the idea of parallel worlds, which do not apply to the individual, who can go broke ([absorbing states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodicity#Markov_chains)), and drop out of the game. Considering longer time sequences, the average over time ($1$ year) will also get rid of the noise, and result in the plot to the right above.

I am having problems reproducing these plots in R. The idea is there, but the drop is much more rapid in the time perspective plot:

[image]

> Is there a much more rapid bankruptcy tendency for the individual player than led to believe by the plots on the talk? Or is it simply differences in the frequency and length of sampling in the original code from the lecture, which is not shared, as for example, less sampling points along the time line?

```
# ENSEMBLE PATTERN:

sam = 60                     # Sixty samples (1 per minute)
mat = matrix(0, sam, 10^6)   # The experiment is repeated 1 million times
  for (i in 1:10^6){  
    mat[1,i] = 100           # Each time the money wagered is $100
    for(j in 2:(sam-1)){     # H's wins 50% tails loses 40%
        mat[j,i] <- mat[j - 1,i] * sample(c(1.5,0.6), 1)
    }
}
plot(rowMeans(mat), type='l', main = 'Ensemble perspective', ylab='Dollars', xlab='Trials', col = 3)


# TIME PATTERN:

set.seed(0)
s = 100                       # Initial money gambled
samples = 60 * 24 * 30 * 12   # Samples at 1 per minute during 12 months
vec = 0                       # Empty vector
vec[1] = 100                  # Starting at $100
for (i in 2:samples) vec[i] <- vec[i - 1] * sample(c(1.5,0.6), 1)
plot(vec, type='l', main = 'Time perspective', ylab='Dollars', xlab='Trials', col = 2)
```

Comment: Did you notice the original plots use logarithmic scales on their vertical axes?

Comment: Could you explain what the "time perspective" plot is attempting to show?  You haven't described what it means to "go broke" or what the absorbing states are.  How could any individual possibly have "$10^{-10000}$" dollars?

Comment: @whuber The ensemble perspective plot does become more of a straight line with the `log = 'y'` option in `plot()`. The one to the left is not corrected, probably because it goes down to zero early on (?).

Comment: Here's my version of the left hand plot, as well as of a simulation of a million individuals tossing 60 coins: `trial <- function(n=60, win=1.5, loss=0.6, start=100) 
  start * exp(cumsum(sample(log(c(win, loss)), n, replace=TRUE)));
sim <- replicate(1e6, trial());
plot(rowMeans(sim), log="y")`  It will take 10-20 seconds.

Comment: @whuber Nice straight line. I'm not sure about the time plot - this is the motivation for the question. Why do you mention $10^{-10000}$? Do you mean that the log is going to be negative? The way I see the plot to the right is that the individual ends up losing the initial $\$100$ very early on.

Comment: I don't understand what is being shown on the vertical axis, but two labels are clear, and one of them is "$10^{-10000}.$"  As far as I can tell, this makes no sense concerning "what happens to me."  I still don't know what it means to "lose the initial \$100," either.  It's never reduced $0$ or a negative value under these rules.

Comment: @whuber I see the x axis (1/2 million simulations) ranging from $0e+00$ to $5e+05$ and the y-axis (dollars) from $0$ to $140.$ Sorry, sorry, sorry... You are referring to the plots on the actual talk... I immediately assumed it was something I did wrong on my plots... :-)

Answer (score 7):

Ole Peter's presented the same material [here](https://youtu.be/CCLtQHL-VUs) with minimal changes, and I tried again to replicate the code, forgetting that I had posted this question until I searched for references to Ole Peter's ergodicity in SE.

This time the code did work out to reproduce the idea, so why not share it? [Here it is](https://github.com/RInterested/SIMULATIONS_and_PROOFS/blob/master/Ole_Peters_San_Petersburg_paradox.ipynb).

And these are the pertinent plots:

The first one corresponds to the plot to the left in the OP, showing the individual trajectories of the first $23$ individuals of an ensemble of $1$ million subjects. The pointwise average for the ensemble corresponds to the return expectation $$\frac 1 2\left(1.5 + 0.6  \right)=1.05$$

or $5$ percent: $100 (1.05)^{60}=\$1,868.$

In black the noise for the ensemble average is smoothed out using $1$ million subjects.

[image]

---

For the second plot I had to reduce the number of tosses from $12$ months ($518400$) to $10,000$ to avoid computationally zero values, and plotted the individual timeline of $10$ subjects:

[image]

This consistent loss over time "reflects the multiplicativity of the process", with $10$ percent loss every two rounds: $1.5 \times 0.6 = 0.9,$ or $5$ percent per round.